# Img get request results in 404 after string encoding to utf-8

Tags: php, html

Sorry If I'm doing a duplicate, but I couldn't find the exact solution to my problem. Since I need my page to be displayed in utf-8, I'm currently reading a file into string using a function that I found, and decoding it:

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
 $content = file_get_contents($fn);
  return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
      mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));}
```

After that, I'm echoing that string in my .php file in order to represent the content in my web-page. However, some img tags src parameters have special characters and where I should have a %F3 character results in a %C3%B3, what consequently will cause a 404 error. My questions: 
Is there any easy way of getting all my string img src parameters and replace them with the correspondent urlencode? 
Am I using the best approach to solve my problem?

Example:
After encoding my string where i should have:

`<img src="https://path/to/file/Convite%20Lan%E7amento%20do%20livro%20Eletr%F3nica.jpg">`

I get:

`<img src="https://path/to/file/Convite%20Lan%C3%A7amento%20do%20livro%20Eletr%C3%B3nica.jpg">`

Comment: show the HTML part where it has the problem, and also show the HTML that you expect it to be correct.

Comment: @Ahmad I don't know if my question was not clear enough, sorry for that. I'm not actually getting a HTML error. After encoding my string where i should have:  


`<img src="https://path/to/file/Convite%20Lan%E7amento%20do%20livro%20Eletr%F3nica.jpg">`   


I get:   



`<img src="https://path/to/file/Convite%20Lan%C3%A7amento%20do%20livro%20Eletr%C3%B3nica.jpg">`

Comment: You need to use regular expression to avoid changing file paths, and only convert any other part of your string.

Comment: @Ahmad thank you for your time. Actually, I knew that regular expressions were one possible solution. However, I was trying to solve my problem with the previous approach because I'm not very comfortable using them. But since it seems that it's the only way, I will try to get a deeper understanding of Regex in order to solve the problem, and if I manage to do it I'll post it out here! Thank you :)